# terminal message and I don't know where it came from

Tags: terminal

I have this message on my terminal each time I open it :
/dev/fd/13:18: command not found: compdef

and when I click it says :
Your file couldn’t be accessedIt may have been moved, edited, or deleted.
ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

I didn't have this before, so I don't know where it come from...

can someone explain to me how to have a "clean" terminal ?

I'm on mackbook

i tried ps like they suggered here :
https://discussions.apple.com/thread/253723739

and got this :

```
Last login: Tue Nov 29 18:56:33 on ttys000
/dev/fd/12:18: command not found: compdef
lealee@MacBook-Pro-de-Lea ~ % ps
  PID TTY           TIME CMD
18250 ttys001    0:00.02 /bin/zsh -l
18384 ttys002    0:00.03 -zsh
lealee@MacBook-Pro-de-Lea ~ %
```

but I don't understand at all what's going on...

Answer (score 0):

Mine came from a auto-completer for AngularCLI in the .zshrc file

to fix:

1. Open terminal
2. type the following `open ~/.zshrc` ((# this opens the zschrc file in a
   simple text editor))
3. delete or comment out the following 2 lines.

> ```
> Load Angular CLI autocompletion.
> source <(ng completion script)
> ```